# ggplot italics only for specific legend rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to adapt this code which makes the legend text italics. For my specific case I am trying to figure out how I could only italicize for example the first 2 values. So in this example, "six" and "eight".

Does anybody have a solution?

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("four", "six", "eight"), values = c("red", "yellow", "blue")) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "italic"))
```

Comment: you could try ggtext - https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext